# Having access to a manager.paypal.com account can I add custom fields to the reports?

Tags: paypal, custom-fields

Is there a way to send custom fields to Paypal so that they can be accessed using the "Custom Report" tool in the paypal manager?

Here are a few examples of the fields:

```
Item Description  
Item Category  
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to page 60 of the [PayFlow Developer documentation](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/payflowgateway_guide.pdf).  There are COMMENT fields that you can use to send whatever data you want, and those fields can also be used for reporting and searching.

Comment: Does that mean I am limited to 2 fields? Can I add more?